# How can I create a index in Elasticsearch with `go-elasticsearch` library?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I am using this library in `go` as Elasticsearch client: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/esapi#IndicesCreate.WithBody

I have a problem on creating a new index with this library. The doc says this method:

```
type IndicesCreate func(index string, o ...func(*IndicesCreateRequest)) (*Response, error)
```

which looks like the one I can use to create the index. But I am new to `go` and not sure how to pass the second parameter.

Below is my code:

```
req := esapi.IndicesCreateRequest{
        Index: indexName,
    }
    esapi.IndicesCreate(indexName, &req)
```

but I got `too many arguments in conversion to esapi.IndicesCreate` error message. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

## New Answer

Based on this [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#mappings), this is answer to your question:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strings"

    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8"
)

func main() {

    client, err := elasticsearch.NewDefaultClient()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    index := "products"
    mapping := `
    {
      "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1
      },
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }`

    res, err := client.Indices.Create(
        index,
        client.Indices.Create.WithBody(strings.NewReader(mapping)),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(res)
}
```

## Old Answer

According to this article:

- [a simple elasticsearch crud example in golang](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6drl/a-simple-elasticsearch-crud-example-in-golang)

All you have to do is:

```bash
export ES_INDEX=products # Linux, MacOS
set ES_INDEX=products # Windows
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "os"

    elasticsearch "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8"
)

var (
    IndexNameEmptyStringError = errors.New("index name cannot be empty string")
    IndexAlreadyExistsError   = errors.New("elasticsearch index already exists")
)

func main() {
    index := os.Getenv("ES_INDEX")
    if index == "" {
        log.Fatal(IndexNameEmptyStringError)
    }

    elastic, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(elasticsearch.Config{
        Addresses: []string{"http://localhost:9200"},
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    response, err := elastic.Indices.Exists([]string{index})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if response.StatusCode != 404 {
        log.Fatal(IndexAlreadyExistsError)
    }

    response, err = elastic.Indices.Create(index)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if response.IsError() {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```